# Slower updating while debugging than in release build

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Ok, so I am building app which has a feature that you can choose some dates displayed on circle and when you make longer touch and swing around this circle they change along. I am using PanResponder for it and setstate when I have to change chosen date. It was laggy for some time but I found that it was one of loops in my code that was causing it and I changed it. Then, when I made a release build it started to be as laggy as it was before change (I was testing it in debug mode with remote debugging). Do you know what can be reason for it?

EDIT:
That's my code:

```
panResponder = PanResponder.create({
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: evt => true,
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
onPanResponderGrant: evt => this.handleTouch(evt),
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => this.handleTouch(evt)
});



getLineLength(initX, x, initY, y) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - initX, 2) + Math.pow(y - initY, 2));
  }

  getCos(a, b, c) {
    return (Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2)) / (2 * a * b);
  }

//function for finding which day is selected
//periodDays = periodLength
  handleTouch(evt) {
    if (evt.nativeEvent.touches.length == 1) {

      if (this.middleOfCircle) {
        let x = evt.nativeEvent.pageX - this.middleOfCircle.x,
          y = -(evt.nativeEvent.pageY - this.middleOfCircle.y),
          topY = this.height,
          aLen = this.getLineLength(0, 0, 0, topY),
          bLen = this.getLineLength(0, x, 0, y),
          cLen = this.getLineLength(0, x, topY, y),
          angle =
            x >= 0
              ? (Math.acos(this.getCos(aLen, bLen, cLen)) * 180) / Math.PI
              : 360 - (Math.acos(this.getCos(aLen, bLen, cLen)) * 180) / Math.PI,
          chosenDay = ~~(angle / (360.0 / this.props.periodDays) + 0.5) + 1;
        if (chosenDay > this.props.periodDays) chosenDay = 1;
        if (this.props.cycleDay != chosenDay) this.props.changeSelectedDay(chosenDay);
      }
      this.counter = 0;
    }
  }
```

and in higher component I pass function for changing day like this:

```
changeSelectedDay={day =>
      this.setState(prevState => {
        if (prevState.selectedDay != day) return { selectedDay: day };
      })
    }
```

and I render it all by .map function like this:

```
//xyValues are a and y values of each view, calculated in componentDidMount
circleOfDates = this.state.xyValues.map((value, i) => (
    //view for every text

    <View
      style={{
        width: 25,
        position: "absolute",
        left: value[0] + CIRCLESIZE + 8,
        bottom: value[1] + CIRCLESIZE + 11,
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
      key={value[2]}>
      {this.getText(i, this.state.xyValues.length)}
    </View>
  ));
```

Comment: how can we possibly begin to try and understand that without seeing any technical info (such as code, build configs, performance testing data)? It's bit like asking a mechanic to fix your car without looking at the engine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please follow when posting on stackoverflow

Comment: Have a look here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance especially this section: "Using console.log statements"

Comment: @ADyson it has a lot of code in it, but I'll try to somehow reduce it and post it here, but generally purpose of my question was to get to know performance changes between debug and release build in react native. But I agree it was poorly asked